# How do you dynamically update an HTML table with Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

Ok, so I have a list of objects (*each object has data on a user*) called `L`. This list is generated with the function `ext.genLeaderboard(limit)`. In the file `leaderboard.html`, I use a for loop to make a table with data on each user. It looks like this:

```html
{% set L = ext.genLeaderboard(100) %}
{% for user in L[:25] %}
<tr>
    <td class="py-2">
    <img src="{{user.avatar}}" alt="image" width="256" height="256" style="border-radius: 50%">
    </td>
    <td><a href="//repl.it/@{{user.name}}">{{user.name}}</a></td>
    <td>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" 
            style="width:{{ext.genUserPercentile(user)['percentile.rounded']}}%" 
            aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
       </div>
    </td>
    <td>{{user.cycles}}</td>
    <td>{{ext.genTimeObj(user.timestamp)["full-date.text"]}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

At the end of this table, I have a "Load More" button:

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block btn-fw">
        Load More...
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the view method from `app.py`:

```py
import extools as ext
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = Cache(app)

@app.route('/lboard')
@app.route('/leaderboard')
@cache.cached(timeout=60)
def lboard():
    return render_template("leaderboard.html", ext=ext)
```

I want to have this button increase the length on the list shown (with splices) when clicked without having to reload the page. I've tried setting the list splice integer to a variable and updating it that way, but I ran into more issues doing it that way.

How can I do this? I've been staring at this problem for an hour now.

Comment: Can you include your view methods? Typically in flask what you do is make additional requests to the same view method to paginate through the datasource using different urlparams.

There are however a lot more elegant ways to do this but that would require some javascript.

Comment: you have to use `JavaScript`/`jQuery` and `AJAX` to update page without reloading.

Comment: OK, but how would I apply that to this situation? I don't have any experience with AJAX.

Comment: now you know that you need `JavaScript` with `AJAX` so you can use Google to find more information. `Flask + JavaScript` was so many times on Stackoverflow so you should find some information. BTW: you can also use `jQuery` which has function [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: here you have some example with jQuery which recevie some data and add to HTML: https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/ajax-button-send-GET-receive-JSON